# Swift idiomatic method to capture gesture recognizer begin state

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uigesturerecognizer

iOS Gesture Recognizers move through different states. It is common (for me at least) to capture reference state at the first beginning state. In ObjectiveC, that might look something like:

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan {
    static NSTimeInterval originalBegin;
    static NSTimeInterval originalEnd;
    static CGFloat originalYOffset;
    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        originalBegin = self.timeAxis.begin;
        originalEnd = self.timeAxis.end;
        originalYOffset = self.yOffset;
    }
    ...
}
```

But Swift does not have static function variables that preserve values between execution of the function. I can turn these kinds of variables into `var`s at the class level, but then it pollutes the variable space of the object, just for variables that are just attached to the particular recognizer.

Is there Swift idiomatic way to capture this pattern locally? Or is this one of those areas where Swift just has friction with UIKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift you can nest a struct, class or enum definition within a function and hold static state there from run to run. For example:

```
func run() {
    enum State { static var counter = 0 }
    State.counter += 1
    print(State.counter)
}

run()
run()
run()
```

Comment: Nice! I experimented and found that I could use any of a local `struct`, `class`, or, `enum`. Is there any reason to prefer the enum as you did in your example? Given I have three values, somehow a local struct with static members seems more appropriate.

Comment: No strong reason I can think of to use one over the others since these are static properties. I prefer enum just because they uniquely can't hold any stored instance properties. One limitation on using nested types within functions/methods is that they aren't currently allowed within Generics.